# Spring ApplicationListener Neo4j BeforeSaveEvent doesn't work with Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

In my Neo4j/Spring Boot application with my Neo4jConfig I have a following hook:

```
    @Bean
    protected ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<BaseEntity>> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<BaseEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent<BaseEntity> event) {
                BaseEntity entity = event.getEntity();
                if (entity.getCreateDate() == null) {
                    entity.setCreateDate(new Date());
                } else {
                    entity.setUpdateDate(new Date());
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

It works perfectly with a previous version of Spring - `4.1.7.RELEASE` but doesn't work with a last version `4.2.0.RELEASE`

I use

`SDN 3.4.0.RC1` and `Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE`

What could be the reason ?

Comment: If BaseEntity is abstract, then it's worth to do a quick check if making it public non-abstract fixes it. If so then this must be a regression of some sort. Can't think anything else right now.

Comment: no, it `public class BaseEntity`

Comment: Then you could do a test with boot 1.3.0.M3 which depends on core 4.2. At least boot 1.2.5 is not officially supported with core 4.2. Also check that you don't have mixed core versions because it's not always easy to update all deps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spring Framework 4.2+ the method in my question must look like:

```
    @EventListener
    public void handleBeforeSaveEvent(BeforeSaveEvent<BaseEntity> event) {
        BaseEntity entity = event.getEntity();
        if (entity.getCreateDate() == null) {
            entity.setCreateDate(new Date());
        } else {
            entity.setUpdateDate(new Date());
        }
    }
```

More details here:  https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2